# Fit div (width) around floating divs

Tags: css, html, word-wrap

I have now searched for hours and couldn't find a workable solution for my problem, so I have you can give me some advice.

What I want is a div that wraps around some floating divs inside. Wrapping the height is no problem to me, but the width doesn't wrap right if the browser is resized to a width, where the floating elements jump down.

Here some example code:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="block1">
    </div>

    <div class="block2">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    border: solid 1px green;
}

.wrapper {
    border: solid 1px red;
    display: table;
}

div {
    display: block; 
}

.block1 {
    float: left;
    width: 390px;
    height: 390px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.block2 {
    float: left;
     width: 390px;
    height: 390px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

So basically I want the wrapping div to always have the width that the divs inside need. By resizing the window and letting the right div jump under the left the wrapping div should now have the width of 390px for this example.

I need this solution for a responsive website I'm trying to make and I need it as soon as possible.

A pure CSS solution would be prefered, but JS or jquery would also do.

Comment: You want the parent div's width to be a multiple of about 390 at all times? Gonna need javascript for that, i think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS media query on the wrapper div. Like so:

```
@media (max-width: 783px) {
 .wrapper {
    max-width: 390px;
  }
}
```

See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mgxBz) for an example:

Comment: thx for the answer.
Sadly even in the example that you linked it doesn't really wrap to 390px if I resize the window. The moment I resize it small enough for the right div to jump down the wrapper just uses the same width as the body.

LG

Comment: That's because you have borders set on the divs so you can see what is where. You'll need to calculate your own specific pixels for your implementation, but for this example, I've updated the codepen to use max-width 783px in the media query (to account for 4 px worth of border). http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mgxBz

Answer (score 0):

Cant you use width or min-width to keep the div 780px on "desktop" and then on lower screen widths that would cause the blocks to wrap, set the width of the parent to 390px. Wrap these in the appropriate media queries and bobs your uncle.....

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is highly likely the only way...

using `$(window).resize`

and: [Javascript Browser Width](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm)

once you know the width of the browser you can divide the available space and specify the width of the wrapper div, thus wrapping your floating divs.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
    white-space: nowrap;
```

to the .wrapper

Answer (score 0):

how about modify this class

```
.wrapper {
border: solid 1px red;
display:table;
**white-space:nowrap;**
}
```

or maybe if you would like to make the left div fix, so if window size change only the right div will be resize

make this for the right div:

```
display: block;
position: absolute;
top:0; 
right:0;
margin-left: *your_fixed_left* px;
```

Comment: The 1. solution doesn't seem to work for me in chrome, as the right div doesn't even jump down anymore, when I resize my window :/

Comment: that white-space nowrap make your inner div not jump down and keep locating on the right top when the outer div resized, if you want to hide inner div (with that fix width: 390px size) add overflow: hidden to the .wrapper (you have to specify the min-width at wrapper div)

Answer (score 0):

Thx for all your help everyone,

I ended up doing it with some JavaScript by reading the window size and setting the wrapper width manually.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div style="display:table-row">

        <div class="block1">
        </div>

        <div class="block2">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>



.wrapper {

    border: solid 1px red;
    display: table;

}

.block1 {

    display:table-cell;
    width: 390px;
    height: 390px;
    background-color: blue;

}

.block2 {

    display:table-cell;
    width: 390px;
    height: 390px;
    background-color: yellow;

}
```